# Images scaled up on iPad air simulation despite retina level resolution. Swift. Xcode v6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swift, retina-display

I'm new to swift an iOS development, and I'm trying to develop a Universal app using spritekit.  I'm using a separate image for iPad resolutions at 2048 x 1536, which is the iPad air's display pixel resolution.  I have no idea what it expects for a rendered resolution.

The problem is, it renders on the screen but is only showing the lower left quarter of the image, and the image is blurry, as if the simulation is rendering display pixels at 1024 x 768.  What am I missing here?  Any help is appreciated.  Here is my code for drawing the background:

```
func drawBackground(){

    // declaring some variables
    var backgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    var backgroundWidth = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background").size.width
    var backgroundHeight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background").size.height


    //check if using an ipad or a iphone
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad){
        backgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backgroundipadair")
        backgroundWidth = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backgroundipadair").size.width
        backgroundHeight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "backgroundipadair").size.height
    } else {
        backgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
        backgroundWidth = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background").size.width
        backgroundHeight = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background").size.height

    }


    // render the image starting from the lower left

    backgroundSprite.position = CGPointMake(backgroundWidth/2, backgroundHeight/2)

    addChild(backgroundSprite)
}
```

Comment: "2048 x 1536, which is the iPad air's display pixel resolution" That is its _pixel_ size, but its _point_ size is 1024 x 768 - it is a 2x resolution device. It is up to you to mark this image as 2x so that it will be scaled to take account of this. (And please stop saying "resolution" when you mean "size".) Your simplest approach is to use the asset catalog; that's what it's for. Otherwise, you need to use the correct naming scheme, which I can see you are not doing.

Comment: I tried it with just background, background@2x...  those images are in my project.  the problem is, when I try to use it without the if statement and just: backgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background") Xcode doesn't recognize that the iPad air has a retina display or something,  and just renders the lowest size image.  This is why I had to use a separate image and include the if statement.  Again,  I'm new to Xcode.

Comment: Does it work in the simulator?

Comment: the image is being rendered.  It's just 4 times the size of the screen.  the image size is definitely 2048 x 1536 and i'm compiling for iPad air.  Oddly enough when I use the usual 2x naming convention, It renders the image at the correct size in the simulation.  The problem is, when I do it that way, it renders the smallest image rather than the @2x image.

Comment: Ok yeah.  Adding @2x at the end of the file name did the trick.  A separate image for iPad is still required since the aspect ratios are different.  Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Addendum for anyone who stumbles upon this post who is having the same problem:  The naming convention for images is iPhone: image.png, image@2x.png, image@3x.png.  iPad: image~ipad.png, image@2x~ipad.png.  By failing to add the ~ipad suffix at the end of the filename, xcode didn't know which image to use for the iPad retina display.  This site proved to be very helpful: http://www.iosres.com/.